# Is there a character limit of the output

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line-interface

I am outputting a base64 encoding of large image files in the command line with imagemagick. I am curious whether there is a character limit on the standard output(1) in the command line in linux. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: There is definitely a max buffer size for stout.  http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe.  In particular, "In Linux versions before 2.6.11, the capacity of a pipe was the same as the system page size (e.g., 4096 bytes on i386). Since Linux 2.6.11, the pipe capacity is 65536 bytes.".  base64 produces only ASCII characters which are 7 + 1 bits.  You probably don't want to be shuffling data around via stdout if you're processing images.

Comment: I was trying out base 64 on Imagemagick a year or so ago and gave up as I could not get it to work. I was using it with php which may have been the problem. Anyway a quote from the Imaagemagick forum "Command-lines can only accept so much data. For a large file you need to put your inline data in a file and reference it, something like inline:@mydata." IM V7 may be better "There is a 4096 character limit to inline data (8192 in IMv7)-- unless its read from a file: " Also there was a bug that should have been fixed with the "inline coder".

Answer (score 1):

There's no limit of stdout.

If you want to make sure of that, just try:

```
cat /dev/urandom > somerandomfile
```

It will rapidly fill up your disk.

Please also note that by default, in a standard C program, stdout is buffered on newline, and there is a buffer limit size.

Comment: how does cat > work behind the scenes?  It's probably buffering and not sending THE BIGGEST THING it can.

Comment: It should be noted that base64 does not include the newline character.

Comment: It's up to `cat`. But  OP's question isn't about `cat`, it's about stdout.

Comment: Let's ignore the base64 encoding for a moment, and assume we are taking the raw file content, outputting it via stdout on the cli, and manipulate it. Compare that with writing to disk, and reading it again to further manipulate it. At first glance, which would be faster?

Answer (score 0):

No. Although terminals don't perform so well with extremely long lines.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with terminals, afaics.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a limit, but you are ***unlikely*** to hit it with an image file: the standard output is (usually) not opened with "large file" support.  This is an issue when redirecting to a file or a pipe (your output could fail at the 4GB size).

The limits for pipes alluded by @Dale to refer to the amount which can be in a pipe before the reader sees the data.

In any case, the filesize will be limited by the available disk space.

Encoding in base64 does not change any of that, except that you will use more space, however the output is used.

Comment: I think that's only on 32-bit systems compiled with a 32-bit off_t, and only if you are opening a file for read. Write to stdout will not have a limit on any linux.

Comment: It actually depends upon the *application*, not the *system*.

Comment: I did some tests: on 64-bit systems, everything is large files everywhere, you don't need any compiler flags or to pass any options to open(). On 32-bit linuxes, you're right, you do need to pass `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` to the compiler to be able to open and write a huge file, or to write a huge file to stdout. The OP is probably 64-bit, so probably has no limits.

Comment: @user894763: strictky speaking, using a 64-bit API doesn't mean there are *no limits*; rather that the limit is very unlikely to be exceeded.

Comment: That's true, you'll run out of disc space eventually. I wonder if `cat </dev/urandom >/dev/null` would ever terminate?

Comment: If you actually tested writing a large-file using a pipe, that might still be running.   Let us know what the elapsed time is, when your testing is complete.

Comment: I wrote a tiny cp program in C and tried `./a.out </dev/urandom >x`. On a 32-bit linux, it failed at 2gb unless I built with `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`. On a 64-bit linux, I stopped it at 3gb or so.